# JS Define a getter function on the prototype show it on the object itself

Tags: javascript

I have the following code that adds a property to the prototype:

```
"use strict";
var User = /** @class */ (function () {
    function User() {
    }
    Object.defineProperty(User.prototype, "prop", {
        get: function () {
            return 1;
        },
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
    });
    return User;
}());
console.log(new User());
```

The output of the console.log function is the following: (in Chrome)

```
User {}
 prop: 1 <====
 __proto__:
  prop: 1 <=====
  constructor: ƒ User()
  get prop: ƒ ()
  __proto__: Object
```

It seems like the property exists on the instance and the `__proto__`. It shouldn't exist only on the `__proto__`?

[image]

Comment: Pretty sure this is the browser displaying things oddly, not the underlying Javascript being faulty. Not sure if it's by design or not

Comment: In Firefox, it shows it as expected. Maybe it's a bug in Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug (or weird "by design" behavior) of Chrome. It works fine in Firefox and Safari.